# If a stream cipher uses a truly random, injective function, can we get rid of epsilon?

Tags: stream-cipher, one-time-pad, semantic-security

Imagine an encryption scheme defined as follows for a fixed $|k|$ and $|m| > |k|$:

- $K = \{0, 1\}^{|k|}$
- $K' = M = C = \{0, 1\}^{|m|}$
- $G: K \rightarrow K'$ is a truly random injective function
- $E(k, m) = m \oplus G(k)$
- $D(k, c) = c \oplus G(k)$

Is this construction semantically secure *without the epsilon* bound? In other words, is it the case that, in the semantic security game, the probability that the adversary guesses correctly which ciphertext they've been given is *exactly* $\frac{1}{2}$?

I'm trying to get an intuition for where the epsilon requirement comes from, and my guess is that it's required since, for real stream ciphers, $G$ is not necessarily injective, and so given a particular $c, m_0, m_1$, it could be the case that there are more keys, $k$, such that $E(k, m_0) = c$ than such that $E(k, m_1) = c$. Is understanding correct?

Comment: If $G$ is [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) then are there default values on $K'$ that are not set by $G$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "default values"?

Maybe this is what you're asking about: Since $|K'| > |K|$, there are values in $K'$ that have no pre-image in $K$ under $G$. But that's true even if $G$ isn't injective.

Comment: I understand the first two steps as defining the spaces, not random assignment. How is $K$ sampled and what are the non-mapped values of $K'$. This missing information makes this Q unanswerable for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is understanding correct?

No, it comes from the requirement that $|m| > |k|$.

Consider this adversary: he picks a random key $k'$.  Then, when he gets the plaintext/ciphertext pair $m, c$, he checks whether $m \oplus G(k') = c$.

If the ciphertext was generated by the encryptor, this will be true with probability $1 / |k|$ (and making $G$ injective makes this exact, rather than a lower bound); if it was generated by a random source, this will be true with probability $1 / |m|$.

Because $1 / |k| > 1 / |m|$, this means that this (rather simple-minded) distinguisher does have a small advantage, hence the $\epsilon$.